# findViewById in Fragment issue

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the textView when the user pick a date.
The line `"TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);"` crashes the app. I get the following error:

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atkSy.png)

Here is the xml:The textView is inside a RelativeLayout, which is inside a LinearLayout, which is inside a ScrollView, which is finally inside a ConstraintLayout.
The id of the TextView is "dateDisplay"

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScheduledMessageActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose Date"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
            android:tag="datePicker"
            android:text="Pick Date" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose Time"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
            android:tag="timePicker"
            android:text="Pick Time" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

And here is the method inside the Fragment class:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    textView.setText("Hello");

}
```

How can I access the TextView?

Comment: Can you also attach the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `textview` a global variable and finds its id in the `onCreateView()` of the fragment. Inside the `onDateSet()` just set the text to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

you should find your views inside `onCreateView` method when you are using a fragment.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myLayout,container,false);

        TextView textView view.findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);

        return view
    }
}
```

as you see you should use `findViewById` method using the view that you inflated for the fragment.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @giroux28 feel free to accept my answer if it worked for you.